# MongoDB filter, orderby, aggregate on the array field?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

this is my document format

```
[
    {
        "name" : "test1",
        "other_name" : "TEST1_1",
        "values" : ["11", "12", "13", "14"]
    },
    {
        "name" : "test2",
        "other_name" : "TEST2_1",
        "values" : ["21", "22", "23", "24"]
    },
    {
        "name" : "test3",
        "other_name" : "TEST3_1",
        "values" : ["11", "32", "13", "14"]
    }
]
```

I want the desired output as:

`["11", "12", "13", "14", "21", "22", "23", "24", "32"]`

I should be able to filter (filter on the values array only), orderby(order by values array only) on them as well.

Can you help me on this?

I tried this:

`db.collection.distinct('values', { "values" : /32/ }).sort();`
but this is returning all the values like `"11", "32", "13", "14"` I want only specific values, can you help on that?

Comment: Your desired o/p has merged unique values from all three docs, what do you mean by  'i want only specific values' ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MongoDB [aggregation operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to get **the desired output**.

We flatten `values` with `$unwind` operator. We sort values. Then we `$group` all documents into single document and store all values (repeated). With `$reduce`, we generate new array with unique values.

**Note:** Aggregation returns array of Objects

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$values"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      values: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      values: {
        $push: "$values"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      values: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$values",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $in: [
                      "$$this",
                      "$$value"
                    ]
                  },
                  [],
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n943sl24HOz)

It's not clear what do you mean with **only specific values**